# Does putting my name on my wife's condo mortgage raise my credit score?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, credit-score

Would it be wise for me to put my name on my wife's condo mortgage (which she owned before we met) to raise my own credit score?

Comment: The answer to this might depend on where you are. Could you comment or edit your post to indicate your country?

Answer (score 6):

If a mortgage contract is between Spouse A and a bank, Spouse B cannot just be added to the contract, as simple as that may sound. Mortgages are not designed for easy addition or subtraction of parties. Therefore, to add (or subtract) a debtor from a mortgage the customary means for doing so is to refinance the loan. A mortgage refinance creates a whole new contract, and may include new terms such as changed debtors, a different interest rate, a new creditor, and a different pay-off date.

Comment: And, very importantly, new ownership, in many cases. If the original title is for the spouse as a single person, adding the other spouse means they also share the ownership now.